# Is it possible to regex match a certain group of letters in python, as long as they don't occur in sequence?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to filter out files from a directory. They typically are named like this:

- `Foo_101.zip`
- `Bar_99.zip`
- `McFoo_103.zip`
- `Baz_HELLO_56.zip`
- `Foo_Bar_99.zip`

My requirements for the filenames I *want* to match are as follows:

1. capitalized (e.g. `Baz_103.zip`)
2. has 1 or more letters (upper- or lower-cased), none of which comprise `HELLO` (e.g. `Foo_Baz_McBar_99.zip`)
3. has 1 or more underscores (e.g. `Foo_Bar_Baz_100.zip`)
4. no underscore may be adjacent to another (e.g. `Foo__Bar_101.zip` is invalid, because there are two underscores adjacent to each other)
5. ends with an underscore and 1 or more digits right before the `.zip` extension (e.g. `Foo_Bar_Baz_100.zip` ends with `_100.zip`)

I need to filter out `Baz_HELLO_56.zip` because it fails the second requirement: it has one or more letters, all of which *comprise* `HELLO`.

Closest I've got with negative lookahead was this:

```
^([A-Z]{,1}[a-zA-Z]+[\-_])+(?!HELLO_\d+.zip)\d+.zip$
```

It manages to exclude `Baz_HELLO_56.zip`. However, it also excludes `McFoo_103.zip`.

Is there any way I could adjust this regex pattern to exclude *only* `Baz_HELLO_56.zip`, but not `McFoo_103.zip`?

Comment: What specifically is it that you are matching? Because you could just do `^Baz_HELLO_56\.zip$` but obviously this isn't what you want.

Comment: I've clarified the requirements in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "it has one or more letters that _comprise_ `HELLO`"? How can _one letter_ "_comprise_ `HELLO`"?

Comment: I see that _part_ of my explanation does not agree with the requirements. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a single lookahead to assert that HELLO does not occur, match an uppercase char followed by mixed upper and lowercase chars.

Then use a repeating pattern that starts with an underscore and matches mixed upper and lowercase chars to prevent adjacent underscores

```
^(?!.*HELLO)[A-Z][A-Za-z]*(?:_[A-Za-z]+)*_\d+\.zip$
```

*About the pattern*

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*HELLO)` Negative lookahead, assert no occurrence of HELLO (or use HELLO_)
- `[A-Z][A-Za-z]*` Match single char A-Z, then 0+ times chars A-Za-z
- `(?:_[A-Za-z]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching `_` followed by 1+ times chars A-Za-z
- `_\d+\.zip` Match `_`, 1+ digits and `.zip`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8rmGf8/1) | [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F!.*HELLO)%5BA-Z%5D%5BA-Za-z%5D*(%3F%3A_%5BA-Za-z%5D%2B)*_%5Cd%2B%5C.zip%24)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with lookaheads that reflect your second and 4th requirements and then matching the whole name, starting with a capital, including letters, `_` and `-`, and ending with `_`, digits and `.zip`:

```
^(?!.*HELLO)(?!.*__)[A-Z][A-Za-z_-]*_\d+\.zip$
```

Note that your third requirement is automatically covered by your 5th requirement.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ylXtRu/7/)